# Tableau - Dotted Line Instead of a Continuous one (Pareto chart)

Tags: tableau-api, pareto-chart

I have followed the directions (video) to create a Pareto chart at http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/pareto-charts

From the start, their lines are continuous and their bar charts are filled in areas under the curve, rather than separate bars.  I am following along with my own data set, and I have dotted lines, and separate bars.

I am following the directions in the video step-by-step, so apparently there is some underlying setting that is different.  I am working from a fresh install of Tableau 10.0.2.

As for the line, the column is CNTD(Product) - continuous and count distinct. The row is SUM(Sales) - continuous and measure(sum).  This is what the video shows, and they have a continuous line.  I have a dotted line.  If I change the count distinct setting, I then get a continuous line, but it changed the bottom horizontal axis from "% of Total Running Sum of Distinct count of Proeduct" to the product names (which are letters).  The video shows the CNTD(), the "% of Total..." and has a continuous line.  How to I get my result to match theirs?

(Windows 8.0; Tableau 10.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

I think what's missing in your description is that you have to do TWO tables calculations. Below is attached the Table Calc settings window, where you have to:

1. Define *Running Total* using specific dimension - in your case it's probably going to be [Product]. In my analysis I've used [Customer Name] from Superstore sample project, which is also what the screen shows.
2. Then you have to select *Add secondary calculation*, where you define *Perfect of Total* and again calculated among the identical specific dimension.

[image]

Also make sure you *Product* dimension is dragged onto *Detail* section of *Marks* shelf and it's sorted accordingly (in my screen, I am using [Customer Name]).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The instructions specifically say to do what you have shown above, so this isn't where the problem is.

Comment: Could you perhaps share you Tableau screen?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that:
1) your pareto chart is of Line type?
2) dual axis for barchart is of Barchart type?
3) barchart size is set to manual?

Answer (score 0):

you must select Line chart if you complete before Edit table calculation.

[image]